# Redux component setState unmounted warning

Tags: typescript, redux, webpack-hmr

Im having trouble with setState on connected component - it shows me warning about unmounted coumponent. Only way i managed to fix it is by writing code like this:

```
import deepEqual = require('deep-equal');
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Prompt } from 'react-router-dom';

// https://github.com/acdlite/flux-standard-action
export type Action<T>{
  type: string
  payload: T
  error?: boolean
  meta?: any
}

const actions: { [name: string]: (payload: any)  => Action<any>} = {
    saveValue: (settings: SettingsState) => ({ type: 'SAVE_SETTINGS', payload: settings }),
};

type StateToProps = {
    value: string;
};
type DispatchToProps = {
    saveValue: (state: SettingsState) => void;
};
type ConnectedProps = {
    header: string;
};

type SettingsProps = StateToProps & DispatchToProps & ConnectedProps;

type SettingsState = {
    value: string;
};

// funky class declaration
let Settings = class extends React.Component<SettingsProps, SettingsState> {
    static mapStateToProps(state: any): StateToProps {
        return {
            ...state.Example,
        };
    }

    static mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: (action: Action<any>) => void): DispatchToProps {
        return {
            saveValue: (settings: SettingsState) => {
                dispatch(actions.saveValue(settings));
            },
        };
    }

    constructor(props: SettingsProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: props.value,
        };
    }

    save = () => this.props.saveValue(this.state);

    onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => { this.setState({ value: e.target.value }); };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
                <button onClick={this.save}>Save</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

// even funkier class variable reassign
Settings = connect<StateToProps, DispatchToProps, SettingsProps>
    (Settings.mapStateToProps, Settings.mapDispatchToProps)(Settings) as any;

export default Settings as React.ComponentClass<ConnectedProps>;
```

it works, but if i change these lines in code:

```
-let Settings = class extends React.Component<SettingsProps, SettingsState> {
+class Settings extends React.Component<SettingsProps, SettingsState> {
```

and one of these:

```
-Settings = connect<StateToProps, DispatchToProps, SettingsProps>
-    (Settings.mapStateToProps, Settings.mapDispatchToProps)(Settings) as any;
+const AnotherVariable = connect<StateToProps, DispatchToProps, SettingsProps>
+    (Settings.mapStateToProps, Settings.mapDispatchToProps)(Settings) as any;

-export default Settings as React.ComponentClass<ConnectedProps>;
+export default AnotherVariable as React.ComponentClass<ConnectedProps>;
```

-or-

```
-Settings = connect<StateToProps, DispatchToProps, SettingsProps>
-    (Settings.mapStateToProps, Settings.mapDispatchToProps)(Settings) as any;
-export default Settings as React.ComponentClass<ConnectedProps>;
+export default connect<StateToProps, DispatchToProps, SettingsProps>
+    (Settings.mapStateToProps, Settings.mapDispatchToProps)(Settings) 
+        as React.ComponentClass<ConnectedProps>;
```

i get this warning:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. 
This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. 
This is a no-op.

Please check the code for the Settings component.
```

witch is wierd, because setState is called from onChange event handler and component is in DOM ...

any idea whats going on?

EDIT: After some testing i found that this code will work:

```
const Another = connect<StateToProps, DispatchToProps, SettingsProps>
    (Settings.mapStateToProps, Settings.mapDispatchToProps)(Settings) as any;
export default Another;

Settings = Another; // setState warning if this line is commented out
```

Comment: At what point to you get this warning?

Comment: basically im having this code <input onchange={e => this.SetState({ value: e.target.value } )} /> rendered by component and warning pops up right after input value change